# Getting a dictionary value where part of the key is in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

Take a dictionary

```
dict = {"word":{"a":{"b":2}}}
```

I want to get the value 2.
To access this I can do this `dict["word"]["a"]["b"]`

However I want to know can I have part of the key (the `["a"]["b]` section) in a string

And refer to it something like this

```
string = "[\"a\"][\"b\"]"

dict["word"]string
```

Or something like that

I know this syntax is incorrect but is it possible to do something like this?

in Python 3.x

EDIT:
A better dict example may be this

```
    dict = {
"word":{"a":{"b":2}}
"hello":{"a":{"b":1}}
"mouse":{"a":{"b":5}}
}
```

How to get the value of b in each case? where you want to avoid hard coding in the `["a"]["b"]` bit of the key in the event that it could change.

Comment: What's the context of using this?

Comment: This might be a case "xy problem" - referring to nested dictionary items via a string in that way is not possible, but what you want to do with that is likely possible... in another way. So, what do you want to do with that?

Comment: Python has an `eval` function which likely could make it work - but I agree with the previous comments.

Comment: you could use somethink like this otherwise: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easydict/

Comment: that one too: https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python

Comment: json file where the first element, in this case "word", will change but the reminder wont

Comment: I don't understand why that requires for you to use this method? Why can't you just get the keys using .keys() method?

Comment: see updated example which may make my question clearer

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `dict` as variable name as it shadows the built-in function.

---

One of the ways to do it is using the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The main idea here is that you are utilizing a regular expression to find out the keys. Once you have the list of keys, extracting data is a easy task.

```
>>> d = {"word":{"a":{"b":2}}}
>>> s = '["a"]["b"]'
>>> import re
>>> keys = re.findall(r'\["(.+?)"\]',s)
>>> d["word"][keys[0]][keys[1]]
2
```

If there are a lot of keys, then you can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from `functools` package. (as JonClements has mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874773/getting-a-dictionary-value-where-part-of-the-key-is-in-a-string/36874916?noredirect=1#comment61316913_36874916))

```
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(dict.__getitem__, keys, d['word'])
2
```

For longer dicts, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> d = {
... "word":{"a":{"b":2}},
... "hello":{"a":{"b":1}},
... "mouse":{"a":{"b":5}}
... }
>>> [functools.reduce(dict.__getitem__, keys, d[i]) for i in d]
[2, 5, 1]
```

However note that due to the unordered nature of the dictionary keys, the output of the list may not be as expected. A better way is to reduce the complete dictionary to a new one (using a dict comprehension), as in

```
>>> {i:functools.reduce(dict.__getitem__, keys, d[i]) for i in d}
{'word': 2, 'mouse': 5, 'hello': 1}
```

Comment: Of course - once you've extracted the keys (in whatever syntax) you can adapt: `functools.reduce(dict.__getitem__, 'ab', d['word'])` to make this more flexible... Just need to get the `'ab'` in a nice syntax (maybe even taking something from `input` and running `ast.literal_eval` on it...)

Comment: Probably want to make the keys a list/tuple instead (ie: keep your original `re.findall` `keys`) of a string in case there's multi-char/non-string keys :)

Comment: And of course - when using the list-comp the order of the values (assuming) they're important may be surprising - unless the source is an `OrderedDict` :)

Comment: @Jon, Yeah. True. Perhaps we can have a list of tuples as in (key,value), Something like `[('word', 2), ('mouse', 5), ('hello', 1)]`.

Comment: Or just a new `dict`? `{'word': 2, 'mouse': 5, 'hello': 1}` - but then we're still guessing at the use the OP has in mind...

Comment: Yes, That would be simpler for the OP. I will add it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to write your own syntax that you would parse. You have to use a charachter that will never appear in the key, a popular example is `.`, but similary, `$`, `|` work as well.

```
def get(d, key):
    kp = key.split('.')
    for k in kp:
        d = d[k]
    return d

d = {'a': {'b': 2}}
get(d, 'a.b')
>>> 2
```

EDIT for the update to the question:

So do you want to be able to get a list of values of a.b specifically in each of those cases? if so you can still use the method above like so

```
d = {
 "word":{"a":{"b":2}},
 "hello":{"a":{"b":1}},
 "mouse":{"a":{"b":5}},
}

# nesting calls to get just to show it is flexible like that
[get(get(d, k), 'a.b') for k in d.keys()]
# if you wanted to generate a dict of {"word": val} it would look like this
{k:get(get(d, k), 'a.b') for k in d.keys()}
```

it even works if your variable part is in the middle

```
d = {
 "x": {"word":{"a":{"b":2}}},
 "x": {"hello":{"a":{"b":1}}},
 "x": {"mouse":{"a":{"b":5}}},
}

# using more calls to get just to show it is flexible like that
[get(get(d, 'x.'+k), 'a.b') for k in get(d, 'x').keys()]
```